# MSBuild error with linked files

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild

When I use msbuild I get the following error:

CS2001 Source file could not be found.

I have noticed the only files that I get this error for are used as a linked reference to the file, so this could be the issue. Any idea's how to get them to build?

I should add that I am able to build the solution in visual studio without a problem.

Hi everyone! Just want to let anyone who cares know what the problem was. It was a length issue as I stated in my comment. I changed the path to just my c drive and everything built fine. Thanks to everyone who took the time to look at this for me. I appreciate it.

Comment: That makes it very important that you build in the correct directory.  So that the relative path name of the file still works.

Comment: I am in the correct directory and I looked at the projects I am having trouble with and it appears all the files are linked correctly. I am really stuck on this one.

Comment: Does any know if this error could be caused by a length issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just want to let anyone who cares know what the problem was. It was a length issue as I stated in my comment. I changed the path to just my c drive and everything built fine. Thanks to everyone who took the time to look at this for me. I appreciate it.