# MSBuild error "CSC : error CS2001: Source File 'x' could not be found" with Linked Files after upgrading to Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, msbuild

After automatically upgrading the project file for a .Net 4.0 web application to work with Visual Studio 2012 everything worked ok at first however when compiling I got lots of errors like this:

> Description : Source File '..\..\..\..\..\File Path' could not be found
>
> File        : CSC

And when trying to build using MSBuild (passing just the project full path, with no additional parameters) in the "Developer Command Prompt for VS2012" I got basically the same errors:

> "CSC : error CS2001: Source File 'x' could not be found"

All errors refer to **Linked Files** (aspx,cs,etc) located in other web applications projects located at a different deep in our code Branch (that's why all the '....\' at the beginning of the paths)

**To me it looks like a problem with the file Length**, I had the same problem a while ago when building the projects on our CI server using MSBuild, I was able to manage it by manipulating the project files before building them using a custom script without the need to move the branch around or reduce the deep of the projects, I didn't have to move anything, the important thing at the time it was that developers using Visual Studio 2010 could compile everything without problems. I learned by this that compiling/Building with MSBuild was different that with DevEnv/VS, and for example MSBuild didn't support building Setup projects and DevEnv did.

Since this is happening now with VS 2012/DevEnv 2012 , plus that VS 2012 doesn't support setup projects anymore (like msbuild), plus VS/DevEnv have the same problem with the file length, it looks like VS 2012 its finally using msbuild under the hood or are more tightly integrated, however I didn't find any article to confirm this.

Changing the branch structure/changing the deep of the projects it’s not an option right now due to several reasons (large code base, high number of projects, risk, timing, effort, etc.).

Does someone have an alternative solution or a fix for this issue in Visual Studio 2012?

Regards,

P.D.: BTW I already checked this post [MSBuild error with linked files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12304645/msbuild-error-with-linked-files) but like I said before changing the paths its not an option right now.

Comment: same issue here, hopefully someone can shed some light on the problem

Comment: Same issue except source file is '' (empty)

Comment: I know this question was posted about a year ago, but I can confirm that there is a file length issue when it comes to referencing source files as linked files in Visual Studio 2012. I ran into this issue a couple days ago mysteriously, and couldn't figure out why Solution Explorer was able to show the files but the compiler (CSC) had issues with finding them. Hopefully this is fixed in VS2013?

Comment: How are your workspace mappings setup for this project? Do you map the team project root? The Branch root? Subfolder of the branch root? Where to? d:\? c:\users\username\documents\Visualstudio2012\Projects? There might be ways to wiggle out of this. As for your question on tighter msbuild integration, yes visual studio integrates better and better into msbuild.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that i did this question a while ago but for what is worth, The approach that we finally went for was:

- Locating the files that were reported as too long.
- Reduce the full path length of those files, by reducing the length of the name and/or
  the length of the container folder or reducing the folder nesting
  level. Therefore reducing the full path length.
- Update the links of the changed files (re-linking) on the dependant projects.

This solved the problem with Visual Studio 2012 on developers workstations and on our CI/Deploy servers that used MSbuild.

For my scenario this approach was less risky,and implied less effort than moving complete projects/solutions to reduce their folder nesting level or reducing the folder names, and have to update all the references of the dependant project/solutions.

Answer (score 4):

Try getting the Build Logs,

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms171470.aspx

it seems that csc task could not find the source file. One cause it you import the wrong file.
so you have to edit the project file via normal Text Editor.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution to this issue, when you linked the file, you relative path is recognized by `msbuild` and go back from there it become your path in a long path however you can change it in the project definition doing right click/unload the project/ and change the path from `../../../` to `$(SolutionDir)/../..` until find the file to link, note: it's extend the character from 255 to 300 character.

Comment: this helped me, i found that We had different version pointing in csproj file and there was no package available in packages. VS never complained about that nor dowloaeded it

Answer (score 1):

1. Check that you have the latest version of the linked files from the other projects.  Visual Studio will NOT automatically get them if they belong to another project.
2. Check that the linked paths are indeed correct.  You can monitor what files VS.NET and MSBUILD are trying to access with the help of the SysInternals ProcMon tool (filter on process names and filter out all successes)
3. If you suspect that the path length is the problem (this will also be visible in the ProcMon tool), you can try to shorten them by linking to the absolute path (C:\X\Y\Z) instead of a relative path (......\Z).  The location of the linked files can then remain unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

My 2 cents to this problem... In my case, I had a file created in one project (i.e. ConfigModel) and I had a link to this file in another project but when I renamed the file ConfigModel in the first project to LoginModel for example, it didn't rename the link in the second project causing this error to occur.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I hit this and solved it today.  I found it by following a msdn tutorial (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379563%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and here's the command that broke for me:

```
csc /t:library /out:MyCodeLibrary.dll simpleType.cs
```

Giving me the message

```
error CS2001: Source file 't:librabry' could not be found
```

Which worked after changing the original command to the following:

```
csc /target:library /out:MyCodeLibrary.dll simpleType.cs
```

I'm not sure why the short version of the /target flag causes this error, but I've not found anywhere else online noting this cause specifically so I wanted to record it here.

Answer (score 1):

This problem arose for me when I reverted to an earlier version of a git repository.  Apparently I didn't add the project file to the repo so when it reverted it didn't revert the project file also.  What I did to clear it up was to exclude the missing .cs file from the project by clicking on the missing file in the project Explorer.  It was easy to find since it was marked with a warning triangle. Then rebuild the entire solution.

Answer (score 1):

1. Verify whether the files mentioned in the error do not exist in the corresponding folder.
2. If their non-existence is intentional, edit the .csproj files and remove the reference for those files.
3. Build again.

Answer (score 1):

I inherited this issue from a project somebody else was working on, **in my case** was a .cs file supposed to be generated by an Entity Framework .tt template, but for some reason it wasn't, so the compiler was going all **CS2001** about that. I had to **update the template and manually run it**, everything worked after that.