# 'CSC:CSC(0,0): Error CS2001: Source file [file] could not be found.' when running a gated check in (C#)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops

I appear to have got in a bit of a mixup with my project and whenever a gated build and check in runs, I get the following errors.....

```
Summary
| Phase 1
15 error(s), 602 warning(s) 
Phase 1 - 15 error(s), 602 warning(s) 
CSC:CSC(0,0): Error CS2001: Source file 'd:\a\3\s\Main\SmartEndPointAssessment\SA.SEPA.Web.UI.Selenium\Features\AssessmentCentreEpaFeatures.feature.cs' could not be found.
CSC:CSC(0,0): Error CS2001: Source file 'd:\a\3\s\Main\SmartEndPointAssessment\SA.SEPA.Web.UI.Selenium\Features\AssessmentCentreFeatures.feature.cs' could not be found.
CSC:CSC(0,0): Error CS2001: Source file 'd:\a\3\s\Main\SmartEndPointAssessment\SA.SEPA.Web.UI.Selenium\Features\AssessorEpaFeatures.feature.cs' could not be found.
CSC:CSC(0,0): Error CS2001: Source file 'd:\a\3\s\Main\SmartEndPointAssessment\SA.SEPA.Web.UI.Selenium\Features\AssessorFeatures.feature.cs' could not be found.
CSC:CSC(0,0): Error CS2001: Source file 'd:\a\3\s\Main\SmartEndPointAssessment\SA.SEPA.Web.UI.Selenium\Features\ClientSettingsFeatures.feature.cs' could not be found.
CSC:CSC(0,0): Error CS2001: Source file 'd:\a\3\s\Main\SmartEndPointAssessment\SA.SEPA.Web.UI.Selenium\Features\CustomFieldFeatures.feature.cs' could not be found.
CSC:CSC(0,0): Error CS2001: Source file 'd:\a\3\s\Main\SmartEndPointAssessment\SA.SEPA.Web.UI.Selenium\Features\EmployerFeatures.feature.cs' could not be found.
CSC:CSC(0,0): Error CS2001: Source file 'd:\a\3\s\Main\SmartEndPointAssessment\SA.SEPA.Web.UI.Selenium\Features\LoginFeatures.feature.cs' could not be found.
CSC:CSC(0,0): Error CS2001: Source file 'd:\a\3\s\Main\SmartEndPointAssessment\SA.SEPA.Web.UI.Selenium\Features\MyProfileFeatures.feature.cs' could not be found.
CSC:CSC(0,0): Error CS2001: Source file 'd:\a\3\s\Main\SmartEndPointAssessment\SA.SEPA.Web.UI.Selenium\Features\ReportFeatures.feature.cs' could not be found.
CSC:CSC(0,0): Error CS2001: Source file 'd:\a\3\s\Main\SmartEndPointAssessment\SA.SEPA.Web.UI.Selenium\Features\SettingsFeatures.feature.cs' could not be found.
```

All these files exist in my local path, and my solution builds and runs. Its when I try to check in I get the errors above.

Looking at the code in source control, the files don't exist. Also these files don't have the '+' icon next to them in solution explorer.

[image]

This is the folder in VSTS...

[image]

How do I get source control to recognize and add these files?

Thanks,

Comment: do you have access to the src files in TFS? if so do a compare and see what you are missing in regards to the version build do you have a team lead who can help you fix this asap..?

Comment: They seem to be part of the solution, but not under source control. Have you tried right-clicking and adding to source control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your screenshoot and the file already checked in TFS source control.  Afraid the root cause  of the error you got  in short currently its the TFVC limitation, from

> ```
> Must not contain more than 259 Unicode characters for a single folder or file name.
> ```
>
> *Source Link: [Version control paths](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/collaborate/naming-restrictions#version-control-paths)*

You have to manually **tweak your file/folder structure**  in TFS source control to bypass this issue. From  `C:\Agent\_work\1\s\TestCaseProject` to `C:\Agent\_work\1\s\TestCasePro`

Reduce the full path length of those files, by reducing the length of the name and/or the length of the container folder or reducing the folder nesting level. Therefore reducing the full path length.

You could also take a look at this similar question: [MSBuild error "CSC : error CS2001: Source File 'x' could not be found" with Linked Files after upgrading to Visual Studio 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16746337/msbuild-error-csc-error-cs2001-source-file-x-could-not-be-found-with-link)