# Build failing on TFS2013 witht the workspace permissions error

Tags: tfs

We have verified the solution file is exist in the folder also it's mapped in to the local workspace.

Source setting on the build directory set as below. Also have confusion in setting build agent folder. Reffered few blogs but nothing works.

```
Source control folder
$/ABC Project/CAP/Spon/SponGroupP/Sponsor                         
Build agent folder
$(SourceDir)

Other Errors and Warnings
2 error(s), 0 warning(s)
 **No matching items found in $/ABC Project/CAP/Spon/SponGroupP/Sponsor in your workspace, or you do not have permission to access them.**
 Exception Message: One or more errors occurred while attempting to create a Label. (type LabelException)Exception Stack Trace:    at System.Activities.Statements.Throw.Execute(CodeActivityContext context)   at System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)   at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)
```

Can someone help me out on this please.

Comment: Does your build service account have appropriate permissions to create labels?

Comment: Hi Rama, did this affect all your build definitions or just the specific one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:

Your file path is too long, there are two Sponsor in your folder structure. Besides, try to tweak the source control path in TFS server, which may do the trick. Details take a look at this question: ['CSC:CSC(0,0): Error CS2001: Source file [file] could not be found.' when running a gated check in (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47517416/csccsc0-0-error-cs2001-source-file-file-could-not-be-found-when-runnin)

---

First try to turn the label sources in **Process--TF Version Control** of your XAML build definition from **True**(default value) to **False**

[image]

This will narrow down if the issue is related to creating label or not. If the build succeed, then you should double check if your build service account have have appropriate permissions to create labels.

Comment: Thanks Patrick for your comments. 
This issue looks to be specific to just one project. on the same build controller other projects are works fine.
As you suggested made changes on the label resources and ran the build it looks like purely permissions issue. Please find the error below.
The file e:\Builds\82\Test 2\Sources\BETA\Sponsor\SponsorGroupP\Sponsor\CTOPSponsor2.0.sln could not be found

Comment: Could you please suggest me on the build permissions which need to set for the build service account which used to run the build service. 

I've already added under build services still it's failed to create project folder on the agent directory. Fails with the error.


TF270003: Failed to copy. Ensure the source directory e:\Builds\83\t

Comment: Hi @Rama , Which account is running TFSBuildService, Network Service ? This account should be an admin of the build agent machine, have enough permission to create folders on `e:\Builds` Besides, according to the solution could not be found, you could manually remote to the build agent machine, check if there are corresponding folder on it. For more ways to trouble shooting and narrow down the issue, you could take a look at this similar question/issue: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e86b9d78-7bd3-425b-80d3-b9db449b2174/tf270003-binary-folder-doesnt-exist?forum=tfssetup

Comment: It's service account, not network service and the account has full permissions. As i said it's specific to one project other projects on this controller able to create ouput folder on agent folders. 


Verified on agent machine but there is no corresponding project folder which is causing the issue. I will try the steps mentioned the blog and update.

Comment: @Rama Try to enlarge  your mapping path for source setting such as `$/ABC Project/CAP/Spon`  instead of `$/ABC Project/CAP/Spon/SponGroupP/Sponsor ` . Did you have multiple solutions under the path, this may also cause such an error. Besides, you could also create a new build definition with the same setting to see if got the same error.

Comment: Thank you Patrick again! but the issue still exist. In the build agent machine the project folder itself not getting created under agent folder.

For example for all project, i could see E:\builds\72\(Project Folder Name) but for this specific project it's not happening.

The file e:\Builds\72\ ADS\CTO0 Test 2\Sources\ ADS\BETA\Sponsor\SponsorP\Sponsor\CT.0\CTOP2.0\CTOP2.0.sln could not be found.
 TF270003: Failed to copy.Ensure the source directory e:\Builds\72\ ADS\CTO0 Test 2\Binaries exists and that you have the appropriate permissions.
Not sure what permissions are missing. pls help

Comment: @Rama Sorry for the later reply due to weekend. If this works well with another project, then it should be enough permission to get files for the build service account. Your file path is too long,  why there are two `Sponsor`  in your folder structure, is this a expected behavior? Besides,
have your tried to tweak the source control path in TFS server, which may do the trick. Details take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47517416/csccsc0-0-error-cs2001-source-file-file-could-not-be-found-when-runnin

Comment: Thank you Patrick. I was able to over come the folder not found issue and the project folder is getting created on build controller. Binaries and Sources are getting copied on the controller build machine without any issues. But still the build failed with access error.

Comment: Thank you Patrick for your help! I was able to over come the folder not found issue and the project folder is getting created on build controller. Binaries and Sources are getting copied on the controller build machine without any issues.

Comment: But still the build failed with access error as below.
$/ABS Project/BETA/Sponsor/SponsorGroupP/Sponsor/CTOPSponsor2.0.sln - 7 error(s), 3 warning(s), 
 e:\Builds\72\ABS Project\CTOPSponsor2.0 Stage Build Test 2\Sources\CTOPSponsor2_0.metaproj: Unable to copy file "e:\Builds\72\ ABS Project\CTOPSponsor2.0 Stage Build Test 2\Binaries\CT_ITC_ALL_CM.dll" to "CTOPSponsor2.0\\Bin\CT_ITC_ALL_CM.dll". Access to the path 'CTOPSponsor2.0\\Bin\CT_ITC_ALL_CM.dll' is denied.  Verified on the build machine and removed the read only flag for the files still the error remains same.  Any thoughts please

Comment: @Rama Glad to here it. Seems the initial issue is fixed. If the comment is limited, you could  create a new case. According to the error info, have you tried to check  if there are read only flag on the folder that holds these files on build agent machine? Also try to set clean workspace= all.

Comment: Thank you Patrick, definetly your inputs helped to narrow down the issue. I will create a new case if i need any further help.